# Understanding simple equality

Tags: cryptography

Looks like I got stucked. Could you please help me to understand that simple equality?

If $A\in\mathbb{N}$ and $B\in\mathbb{N}$ than why do we have

$$
    (7^B \pmod{11})^A \pmod{11} = (7^A \pmod{11})^B \pmod{11} ?
$$

Comment: Work in a field. What field ?

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography if it`s important

Comment: Both are just $7^{AB}\bmod 11$. Reducing mod 11 halfway through does not affect the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, ignore the $\pmod {11}$s and you have $(7^A)^B=7^{AB}=(7^B)^A$  The outer $\pmod {11}$ clearly is no trouble-you just have to convince yourself the inner one isn't either.

Comment: Yeah, of course! Thanks